# ES6 functions help - functions returning functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i am very new to ES6.

Trying to go through some tests to learn.

Please help me on this on what should be the implementation to pass the tests.

```js
// dependencies:
const expect = require('chai').expect;

 // implement this:
 function b(x){
   // return "b"+ x;
   //  return (x) =>  "bo" + x;
    
 }
// unit tests:
describe("implement function b", function() {
  it("SHOULD work for the following cases", function() {
    console.log(b()("m"));
    expect(b("m")).to.equal("bm");
    expect(b()("m")).to.equal("bom");
    expect(b()()("m")).to.equal("boom");
    expect(b()()()("m")).to.equal("booom");
    expect(b()()()()("t")).to.equal("boooot");
  });
});
```

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible but a bit weird and I would never do something like this in real life.

In general, a function that returns a function is called a "second-order" function. A function that returns a function that returns a function is a "third-order" function. What you're trying to do is write a function that is has a different order depending on the arguments, which is really confusing to read and maintain.

Having said that, javascript isn't fussy about return types, so you can do it. Here's the code I'd use (uses ES6 default variables and recursion)

```js
function b(lastLetter, prefix = "b") {
  if (lastLetter) {
    //if we're ending the chain, return everything so far with the last letter on the end
    return prefix + lastLetter;
  }
  //if not, then return version of this function with a slightly longer prefix
  return lastLetter => b(lastLetter, prefix + "o");
}

console.log( b("m") );
console.log( b()("m") );
console.log( b()()("m") );
console.log( b()()()()()()()("t") );
```

Comment: I considered this, but didn't like using a second parameter that way and used a closure instead. Does the job though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a closure and named function expression, see comments. I don't like the repeated line but can't avoid it with this pattern.

```js
function b(x) {

  // On the first call, setup prefix 
  var prefix = 'b';

  // End early if x provided on first call
  if (x) return prefix + x;

  // Otherwise, return a function that can be chained
  return function foo(x){
    prefix += 'o';
    if (x) return prefix + x;
    return foo;
  } 
}

console.log(b('m'));
console.log(b()('m'));
console.log(b()()('m'));
console.log(b()()()('m'));
console.log(b()()()()('t'));
```

The problems with this pattern are:

1. If no letter is provided in the last call, it returns a function. There's no way for a particular call to know it's the last.
2. If a call is made after a letter is provided, it will attempt to call a string, which will throw an error. Again, there's no way to stop the call once a letter is provided if the user attempts it.

Comment: Yes, I agree, which is one of the reasons why I strongly discourage this approach! It does pass the tests though.

Comment: @DuncanThacker Your solution has same problems :P even a few more than this one. I wonder why you **strongly discourage** this approach? Because this approach is better than your approach.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - the question is trying to accomplish something that I would never try to do in real life. Your solution (and mine) correctly answer the question, I wasn't trying to put your answer down,

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `b` has to return a function if no argument is passed to it. This function acts the same way: if no argument is passed to it, it returns itself. Moreover, we have to keep track of how many times our function was called.

The following solution creates an inner function which increments the count if its argument is falsy, otherwise it creates a string that consists of `"b"`, `"o"` repeated as many times as the count specifies and the value of the argument:

```js
const b = v => {
  let n = 0; // this is our counter
  const f = e => {
    if (e !== undefined) {
      // an argument was passed, return the correct value
      return 'b' + 'o'.repeat(n) + e;
    }
    // no argument was passed, increment the counter and return the function
    n += 1;
    return f;
  };
  // call the function the first time with the initial value
  return f(v);
};

console.log(b('m'));
console.log(b()('m'));
console.log(b()()('m'));
console.log(b()()()('m'));
console.log(b()()()('t'));
```